# Remove data rows if sum is less than X for two conditions in R

Tags: r

I am looking at the number of whales in two gulfs. My data is structured like this:

```
  | Date  |Gulf |Calf |Adult |ALL |
------------------------------
 1|  9/09 | G   | 2   | 18   | 20
 2|  9/09 | S   | 1   | 20   | 21
 3| 10/09 | G   | 5   | 2    | 7
 4| 10/09 | S   | 3   | 2    | 5
```

I would like to use R to remove dates that have 15 or fewer total whales over both gulfs as well as gulfs that have less than two calves. The output in this example would look like:

```
  | Date  |Gulf |Calf |Adult |ALL |
------------------------------
 1|  9/09 | G   | 2   | 18   | 20
```

Row #2 had fewer than 2 calves in gulf S and rows #3 and #4 had a total of 12 whales that day which is fewer than 16. I have tried:

```
sum <- plyr::ddply(Gs, c("Date", "Gulf"), numcolwise(sum))

morethanone<-(sum %>%
  group_by(Date,Gulf) %>%
  summarise(Calf=(Calf[Calf > 1]),Date, Gulf))
```

This code gets rid of gulfs with less than 2 whales, but then my data is summed by date/gulf which I don't want. I also still have to figure out how to get rid of days with 15 or fewer total whales over both gulfs.

Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: What variable do tell you the number of whales?

Comment: The calf and adult columns tell you the number of whales in that age group and the ALL column is the sum of those two columns. Thank you for your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R option might be using `subset` like below

```
subset(df,ave(ALL,Date,FUN = min)>15 & Calf >=2)
```

or

```
subset(df,ave(ALL>15,Date,FUN = all) & Calf >=2)
```

which gives

```
  Date Gulf Calf Adult ALL
1 9/09    G    2    18  20
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Date = c("9/09", "9/09", "10/09", "10/09"), Gulf = c("G", 
"S", "G", "S"), Calf = c(2L, 1L, 5L, 3L), Adult = c(18L, 20L,
2L, 2L), ALL = c(20L, 21L, 7L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Date) %>% 
   filter(all(ALL > 15), Calf >= 2)
# A tibble: 1 x 5
# Groups:   Date [1]
#  Date  Gulf   Calf Adult   ALL
#  <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#1 9/09  G         2    18    20
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("9/09", "9/09", "10/09", "10/09"), Gulf = c("G", 
"S", "G", "S"), Calf = c(2L, 1L, 5L, 3L), Adult = c(18L, 20L,
2L, 2L), ALL = c(20L, 21L, 7L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",
"2", "3", "4"))
```